# bxslider javascript install

Tags: javascript, html, installation, bxslider

Hi I cannot get bxslider to work in my HTML file, i have downloaded all the files and put them into the relevant directories etc but my images are just displayed one after another in block format when i run the page in firefox.

The code i am using is as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
   <title>AC</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <meta name="author" content="AC" />
    <meta name="description" content="AC" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="AC" />
    <link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<link href="http://bxslider.com/lib/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="images/pic1.jpg" title="An Energy Conservation Company"></li>
 <li><img src="images/pic2.jpg" title="Designers and Manufactors of Quality Lighting Controls"></li>
<li><img src="images/pic3.jpg" title="Caption to go here"></li>

</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
mode: fade,
captions: true,
auto: true,
autoControls: false
});
});
</script>

<div id="header">
<div id="headerleft"><a href="./index.html"><img src="./images/mainlogo.jpg" alt="AC"/></div>
<div id="headerright">
<div id="userbar">userbar</div>
<div id="socialbar">socialbar</div>
<div id="basket">basket</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="navmenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="./girls.html">Girls</a></li>
<li><a href="./boys.html">Boys</a></li>
<li><a href="./unisex.html">Unisex</a></li>
<li><a href="./accessories.html">Accessories</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="content">
<div id="gallery">
</div>
<div id="offers">offers</div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
<div id="cards">MAESTRO VISA</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in your script. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: fade,
    captions: true,
    auto: true,
    autoControls: false
  });
})
```